# Getting Student's Code who failed more than 45% of their tests

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL
So, I want to return all the student's unique code who have failed more than 45% of their tests that they've taken.

Comment: This question is poorly phrased. Could you edit it to say what you want to do, rather than your application?

Comment: You are cross join a1,a2. Fix `From ( ... )  a1 LEFT JOIN (...) a2 ON a1.code=a2.code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

Assume as in your data `- Grade (75 or above is passing) => grade < 75 is failed`

```
SELECT code
FROM exams
GROUP BY code
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN grade < 75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) :: FLOAT / COUNT(grade) > 0.45;
```

This is [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/10717/7)

Comment: SELECT code  

FROM students, exams  

GROUP BY code  
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN exams.grade < 75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(exams.grade) > 0.3;  

I edited it because of errors with From and grade, but I get no rows from this

Comment: Hmmm still no rows being outputted. I think the recommended way to do this is to calculate the total tests and the total failed tests per student and compare those two columns, but I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. Thanks!

Comment: @thefalsehuman edited my answer. That is exactly what it did, calculate the number of failed exams, then divine by total exams. Must convert to float first or the divine will be FLOORed  to nearest integer (0)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply write this as:

```
SELECT e.code
FROM exams e
GROUP BY e.code
HAVING AVG( (e.grade < 75)::numeric ) > 0.45;
```